# With exactly the same workload one server shows high cpu load

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, io, load

I'm running hadoop and have 2 identically configured servers in the cluster. They're running the same task, same configuration, same everything, and both are totally dedicated as hadoop task nodes (workers).

The job I'm running through this cluster is highly IO bound.

On one server I see `60-100MB/sec` of `IO` and a `CPU load` of `5-10`, on the other server I see `40-60MB/sec` of `IO` and a `CPU load of 60-90` (and the box is almost unusable in terms of even running a simple shell).

I've run `smartctl` and don't get any disk warnings.

[image]

Any suggestsions on what I might do next to identify the root difference between these boxes? These results have been consistent over many hours of processing.

Comment: take a look at the output of iostat, it will help you figure out if this is caused by a particular disk..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It smells of partition misalignment on 4096-byte physical / 512-byte logical disk sectors.